# Build Every 4 columns a row

Tags: php, html-table

How can I make every 4 columns it's own row in a table?  Please don't tell me I should do them as div's, this needs to be a table...

Here's my code:

```
        $tmpRet = array_filter($ret, function($e){
            return ($e['categoryID'] == 6) ? $e : null;
            });
        $tmpRet = array_values($tmpRet);
        $tmpCt = count($tmpRet);
        $counter = 0;
        echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">' . PHP_EOL;
        for($i = 0; $i < $tmpCt; ++$i){
            $counter ++;
            echo ($i == 0 || $i % 4 === 0) ? '  <tr>' . PHP_EOL : null;

            echo '<td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponUrl'] . '" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/' . GetLogoPath($tmpRet[$i]['showType']) . '/images/sponsors/' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponFileName'] . '" alt="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" title="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>' . PHP_EOL;

            echo ($i == 0 || $i % 4 === 0) ? '  </tr>' . PHP_EOL : null;
        }
        echo '</table>';
```

And It's spitting out:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.adp.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/ADP_logo_tag_R_rgb 4-11-13.jpg" alt="ADP" title="ADP" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://ascensus.com/RetirementPlanSolutions/index.htm" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/Ascensus - color.jpg" alt="Ascensus" title="Ascensus" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.getbridgepoint.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/Bridgepoint 2012.JPG" alt="Bridgepoint" title="Bridgepoint" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.brightscope.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/BrightScope_Logo JPEG 10-10-12 approved.jpg" alt="BrightScope" title="BrightScope" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.corporateinsight.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/Corporate Insight Logo JPEG 9-26-12.JPG" alt="Corporate Insight" title="Corporate Insight" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.guardianlife.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/Guardian Logo from 2011 OK.JPG" alt="Guardian" title="Guardian" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.infosysbpo.com" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/Infosys McCamish_natural_vert_nt jpeg.JPG" alt="Infosys McCamish" title="Infosys McCamish" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://ing.us/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/INGC300.JPG" alt="ING" title="ING" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="https://www.janus.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/JANUS logoJPEG created 9-20-12.jpg" alt="Janus Capital Group" title="Janus Capital Group" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.jpmorgan.com/pages/jpmorgan" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/JP Morgan Logo for infotree.JPG" alt="JP Morgan" title="JP Morgan" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.newkirk.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/Newkirk a DST Co 4-23-13.JPG" alt="Newkirk" title="Newkirk" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.oculuspartners.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/Oculus_logo_v4-vert.jpg" alt="Oculus" title="Oculus" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://us.pioneerinvestments.com" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/Pioneer Investments Jpeg ogo.JPG" alt="Pioneer Investments" title="Pioneer Investments" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.processunity.com/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/ProcessUnity logo JPEG created 9-20-12.jpg" alt="ProcessUnity" title="ProcessUnity" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.prudential.com/view/page/public" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/Prudential Blue Gray for Lanyards.JPG" alt="Prudential" title="Prudential" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.rrdonnelley.com" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/RR Donnelley Logo for Mints.JPG" alt="RR Donnelley" title="RR Donnelley" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="http://fc.standardandpoors.com/sites/client/us/crpsite/" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/spark-forum/images/sponsors/sp_capitaliq_fc_logo.jpg" alt="S&P Capital IQ" title="S&P Capital IQ" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Couple of issues first `$counter` and `$i` are the same value at all times in that code, you not appear to need both.  Also you need to `urlencode()` the `$tmpRet[$i]['sponFileName']` variable as the filenames have characters in need of conversion in them, like spaces.

Comment: Also you do not want to `echo NULL`, you want to `echo ""`.

Comment: If you notice $counter is not used...  that was for something else...

Comment: My preferred method to do this is nest two loops.  With the code you have, your final `</tr>` will be missing unless your final row has exactly 4 items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replace the relevant lines in your code with these:

```
// At column 0 you create a new row <tr>
echo $i % 4 == 0 ? "<tr>\n" : "";

// At column 3 you end the row </tr>
echo $i % 4 == 3 ? "</tr>\n" : "";
```

This creates 4 columns per row.

#### Edit to accommodate cases where there may be coluumns that are not a multiple of 4

```
echo "<table>\n";

$colSpan = 4;
$rows = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    // At column 0 you create a new row <tr>
    if($i % $colSpan == 0) {
        $rows++;
        echo "<tr>\n";
    }

    echo "<td>" . ($i + 1) . "</td>\n";

    // At column 3 you end the row </tr>
    echo $i % $colSpan == 3 ? "</tr>\n" : "";
}

// Say you have 5 columns, you need to create 3 empty <td> to validate your table!
for($j = $i; $j < ($colSpan * $rows); $j++) {
    echo "<td></td>\n";
}

// Add the final <tr>
if(($colSpan * $rows) > $i) {
    echo "</tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>\n";
```

And this should create near enough perfect `<table></table>` structure! Enjoy.

Comment: you would also have to print a `</tr>` outside the loop in the event that the total quantity is not evenly divisible by 4.

Comment: This works perfectly!  Would you happen to know how I can get the last row to split the columns?   Say I have 6 columns, so it would be 1 row with 4, 1 row with 2 (but with a colspan="2")?   It'd have to compensate for 5 or 7 items as well...   or should I post this as another question?

Comment: Sorry I was away from computer. Erm.. does it absolutely _need_ to be dynamic? I wouldn't be able to give you a definite answer without knowing your data. One solution is you refrain from putting the last 6 items in the data array, then manually create a final row of data as such: `<tr><td colspan="4">[TABLE HERE WITH 6 COLUMNS]</td></tr>`
This is how I'd do it.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to echo a `</tr>` right before you echo a `<tr>` unless it's the first time through.

```
echo "<tr>";
for($i = 0; $i < $tmpCt; ++$i){
    $counter ++;
    // echo a row close right before you row open unless it's the first one
    echo ($i != 0 || $i % 4 === 0) ? '  </tr><tr>' . PHP_EOL : null;
    echo '<td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponUrl'] . '" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/' . GetLogoPath($tmpRet[$i]['showType']) . '/images/sponsors/' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponFileName'] . '" alt="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" title="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>' . PHP_EOL;
}
// close out the last row
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Better yet, echo the first `<tr>` before the loop, and on `$i % 4 === 0` echo `</tr><tr>`.  Then echo a `</tr>` after the loop.  It cuts down the decisions by half.

Comment: @SurrealDreams that would give comparable results and eliminate an if.. good solution.

Comment: @SurrealDreams Changed answer to reflect your suggestion

Comment: Also a good solution. It doesn't maintain the logic of start row->contents->end row in the loops themselves, but it makes the loops simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with nested `for` loops:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $tmpCt; ++$i){
    $counter ++;
    echo '  <tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    for($j = 0; $j < 4 && $i < $tmpCt; ++$j, ++$i){
        echo '<td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponUrl'] . '" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/' . GetLogoPath($tmpRet[$i]['showType']) . '/images/sponsors/' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponFileName'] . '" alt="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" title="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '  </tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

One thing that might go wrong is that maybe PHP doesn't support `for` loops where two incrementations happen (haven't tested it), so if it doesn't, just put the `++$i` at the end of the inner `for` loop.

This will go through 4 columns or until the last column is found. This way $j is a simple counter to 4, and $i is still the reference for the array. Now in pseudocode, it's

```
for(every column){
    start row;
    for(4 iterations){
        print or use the contents of a column;
    }
    end row;
}
```

**EDIT**
As OrangePill suggested, this would also work

```
for($i = 0; $i < $tmpCt; $i+=4){
    $counter ++;
    echo '  <tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    for($j = 0; $j < 4 && $i+$j < $tmpCt; ++$j){
        echo '<td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="' . $tmpRet[$i+$j]['sponUrl'] . '" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/' . GetLogoPath($tmpRet[$i+$j]['showType']) . '/images/sponsors/' . $tmpRet[$i+$j]['sponFileName'] . '" alt="' . $tmpRet[$i+$j]['sponName'] . '" title="' . $tmpRet[$i+$j]['sponName'] . '" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '  </tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: +1 ... this is a nice solution. You could also increment the outer loop by `$i+=4` access the array property as `$tmpReturn[$i+$j]` so you don't have to increment both.

Comment: That would work. The choice between the two would probably be mostly preference-based, though. For example, I would personally prefer to use a single variable to indicate an array index, but I can understand that others might not want to see `$i` being incremented in a loop other than its own. I'll put in a second section to show what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">' . PHP_EOL . '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
        for($i = 1; $i <= $tmpCt; ++$i){

            echo '<td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponUrl'] . '" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/' . GetLogoPath($tmpRet[$i]['showType']) . '/images/sponsors/' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponFileName'] . '" alt="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" title="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>' . PHP_EOL;

            echo ($i % 4 === 0) ? '  <tr>' . PHP_EOL .'</tr>' . PHP_EOL : null;
        }

        for($j = 1; $j <= (4 - $tmpCT % 4); $j++){
            echo '<td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>' . PHP_EOL;
        }

    echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL . '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple issues.

First, you're wrapping you first and every fourth cell in a tr.

Try changing this:

```
    echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">' . PHP_EOL;
    for($i = 0; $i < $tmpCt; ++$i){
        $counter ++;
        echo ($i == 0 || $i % 4 === 0) ? '  <tr>' . PHP_EOL : null;

        echo '<td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponUrl'] . '" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/' . GetLogoPath($tmpRet[$i]['showType']) . '/images/sponsors/' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponFileName'] . '" alt="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" title="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>' . PHP_EOL;

        echo ($i == 0 || $i % 4 === 0) ? '  </tr>' . PHP_EOL : null;
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

To this:

```
    echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<tr>';//start first row
    for($i = 0; $i < $tmpCt; ++$i){
        $counter ++;
        echo '<td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponUrl'] . '" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://sparkusa.org/' . GetLogoPath($tmpRet[$i]['showType']) . '/images/sponsors/' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponFileName'] . '" alt="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" title="' . $tmpRet[$i]['sponName'] . '" style="max-height:85px;" /></a></td>' . PHP_EOL;

        echo ($i == 0 || $i % 4 === 0) ? '</tr><tr>' . PHP_EOL : null;//end row after every fourth cell and start a new one
    }
    echo '</tr>';//close out last row
    echo '</table>';
```

Depending on how your page is laying out, you may have to insert some empty table cells in the last row, in case your record count isn't evenly divisible by 4.